# How to set igraph edge attributes to strings using a gml format file?

Tags: r, igraph

I using GML graph file format to read a graph into igraph (R version). Is there a way to set edge attributes to be strings? It seems that some attribute labels are permitted to have string values while others are not. Sample input file:

```
graph [
node [
    id 1
    control 1
    label "CiscoSW-1"
]
node [
    id 2
    control 1
    label "CiscoSW-z"
]
edge [
    source 1
    target 2
    difficulty 'A,B,C'
    label "CiscoSW-1"
]
]
```

Comment: I think the issue could be the the use of `' '` in difficult rather than `" "` . You could `gsub` these out, and then it should work

Comment: holy cow ... feeling stupid right now... thanks!

Comment: Using `'` in GML files is not valid. See the GML specs for more information. Future versions of igraph will show an error like this: "Parse error in GML file, line 15 (syntax error, unexpected ERROR, expecting string or number or [) - Parse error." Not perfect, but at least it indicates the line where things went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if `read_graph` doesn't like single quotes `' '`, so you will need to swap these out for double quotes `" "`.

One way to do this is by reading in the file, `gsub`ing out the offending quotes, and then reading it in again with `read_graph`. So if your graph file is saved as `so.gml`, then

```
# Read in file, `gsub` quotes and write to tempfile()
r <- gsub("[']", "\"", readLines("so.gml"))
cat(r, file=temp<-tempfile())

# Read amended gml file 
g <- read_graph(temp, format="gml")
```

Check edge attributes are as expected

```
edge.attributes(g)
```